# CSS3 Transform starts working after resizing window on Mozilla

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, mozilla, parallax

I'm writing a pure CSS3 parallax webpage following [Keith Clark's](http://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites/) method and a sample made by Carl Henderson (Can't link his codepen due to lack of reputation).
This is the code in main page, my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zm1a0gqz/), and Carl's Codepen.

**index.html**

```
    <div class="plax_layer plax_layer--back">
    <p>Back Layer</p>
    </div>

    <div class="plax_layer plax_layer--base">
        <p>Base Layer</p>
    </div>

    <div class="plax_layer plax_layer--deep">
        <p>Deep Layer</p>
    </div>

</div>
```

**main.css**

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.parallax {
    top: 0;
    -webkit-perspective: 1px;
    -moz-perspective: 1px;
    -ms-perspective: 1px;
    perspective: 1px;
    height: 100vh;
   overflow-x: hidden;
}
.plax_layer {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   right: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   font-size: 200%;
   -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
   -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
   -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
   -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
   transform-style: preserve-3d;    
}
.plax_layer--base {
    -webkit-transform: translatez(0) scale(1);
    -moz-transform: translatez(0) scale(1);
    -ms-transform: translatez(0) scale(1);
    -o-transform: translatez(0) scale(1);
    transform: translatez(0) scale(1);
    border: 2px solid red;
}

.plax_layer--back {
    -webkit-transform: translatez(-1px) scale(2);
    -moz-transform: translatez(-1px) scale(2);
    -ms-transform: translatez(-1px) scale(2);
    -o-transform: translatez(-1px) scale(2);
    transform: translatez(-1px) scale(2);
    border: 2px solid blue;
}
.plax_layer--deep {
    -webkit-transform: translatez(-2px) scale(3);
    -moz-transform: translatez(-2px) scale(3);
    -ms-transform: translatez(-2px) scale(3);
    -o-transform: translatez(-2px) scale(3);
    transform: translatez(-2px) scale(3);
    border: 2px solid green;
}
p {
   position: absolute;
}
```

The problem I'm having is the code works fine on Chrome and Safari, but Mozilla completely fails to give the effect without opening Inspector window (stops after closing said window) and only works in my Fiddle after I've resized the output window. I haven't encountered similar problems (maybe yet) on google.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix by adding `margin: 0` to the body.

Check it out here: http://codepen.io/lonekorean/pen/0e625cea8f2da7e046ea2b3b9a33c9cc .

Comment: Now it works in the fiddle without resizing, but not on my main page http://kp.mittensland.net